# How to determine signal strength from an esp8266 module and a Rasberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, mqtt, esp8266

I am trying to write a python script which will determine which of two esp8266 modules is closest to my raspberry pi.

My setup is as followed: I am using a Raspberry pi 3 with the raspbian operating system installed. Currently my raspberry pi acts as an MQTT broker to pick up messages sent out by the esp8266 modules. However I need a way in which to determine, if two esp8266 send a message, which one is nearest to the raspberry pi

Comment: Do you use your Raspberry Pi as an access point with the ESP8266 connected as stations?

Comment: Unless the above is true (i.e. the Pi is the Access Point for the ESP's) there's no easy way to do what you want